# MySQL database is glitchy after moving servers

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just exported a MySQL database from one server and imported it into another server. However, my application (WordPress) can read some information from the database but not others. For example, WordPress can still access the posts but the permalinks are messed up. Right now, my blog has a ton of issues because of this. I remember encountering this problem before in the past, but I forgot how I solved it. The old server version was `5.5.16-log`, the new server is `5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2`.

How can I fix this using phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ the paths for the posts are absolute paths and stored as serialized data in the database. Please read this link to learn how to safely migrate a Wordpress installation.